# How to fit a mini fridge in between two non-straight walls?

Tags: walls, kitchens, refrigerator, cabinets

I have two cove walls in a kitchen at about ~24" out and 29 5/8" apart.

The wall on the left supports the right side of a dual oven.

In between them is high cabinets (the lower cabinets removed for fridge).

The wall on the right is majorly load bear and full of studs.

Problem... I have a 29 1/2" wide mini fridge.   Should fit right?    No.   Neither wall is at a right angle to the floor and both have some nuances.   I can adjust the legs and get it to slide in but it is tight and scraping the wall.   Also I have to be able to get this thing out in the future without damaging granite pad above it.

I get that I can take out the drywall or reduce the drywall where fridge will be but it seems that may look a bit off when the wall continues at a different width.    Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible to change the common 1/2 inch drywall to 1/4 inch drywall.  That should give an extra 1/2 inch space without much change in looks.

Comment: Very wide feathering of the drywall mud should almost hide the 1/4 inch to 1/2 inch difference.

Comment: @crip659 - that is where I was going in my head.    Not sure I have feathered that much before.    Also really only care about the inside corners which are very visible.

Comment: My dad would probably get his mistake hammer(big sledge) to make the walls right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider removing all the drywall on the sides and replacing with 1/4" plywood. Assuming that the existing drywall is 1/2" thick this should result in a net gain of 1/2" of width. Replacement corner beading will work just fine against one side being plywood and you can mud that in just as if it was drywall.

Since you have an implied dividing line at counter height (i.e. reference to "granite pad") you could also elect to replace the drywall along the inside of the back of the mini-frige cubby with plywood as well. It might make finishing the side plywood to rear wall easier.

Comment: good advice on the plywood.   I currently have one side out at height and can take the other out in a few mins.   However not sure how I get the metal corner strip "straight".   It is pretty beat up bad on the other side already, salvageable but beat up.   The front corners are going to be right in the middle of the kitchen, the finish here is important.

Comment: I would remove the beat up corner strips entirely and then replace with new ones. Trying to adjust the existing ones to the new 1/4" offset will be next to impossible. I realize this means having to remud the facing ends of the stub walls but that is the tradeoff here.

Comment: Yea I know I "should" but 9 feet ... ugg.

Comment: Why 9 feet? Are you talking about 9 feet of total corner beading replacement or one particular one with a total 9 foot length? If the latter I fail to see why that would be necessary if you can split at the granite pad level.

Comment: If anyone notices a 1/4" difference in wall thickness over a gap of the counter top, give 'em a beverage of their choice as a prize for having a well calibrated eyeball! If the choice tends toward "adult" beverages, after one or two, they'll no longer see the difference. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan - I get you.    Logically it seems like easy and no big deal.   Just pains me that I have to do this for the first time in ~20+ years.